# Google maps API v3 - Gray out or remove states?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to either gray out, or even better remove all together, states I do not want to see from the map? Not able to find any clear answers on this when searching. I am attempting to show just a map of Texas and place markers on it.

Thanks!

Comment: What about other countries?  Have you considered custom tiles?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [this (v2) example](http://maps.forum.nu/gm_texas.html) by [Marcelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408519/marcelo)?

Here is a [v3 example using FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_State_invert4.html?state=Texas)

You can also do the same thing with [KmlLayers](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_nosidebar.html?lat=37.155939&lng=-79.497071&zoom=6&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/virginia_inverted_kml.xml)

Comment: It was using v2 of the API, but looked pretty much like my two examples.  Marcelo probably let his domain expire.