# Show only one state in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to make a mobile app with HTML5 and want to show you a map, but the map should only be one state, for example, only show the state of Texas and nothing else, they could see other states or regions.

I did not find something useful, all I've found are tutorials to center the map in a region but still can't move through other states and countries.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: One thing you could do is use mapsengine.google.com to draw polygons over all areas you don't want visible. Then set the polygon transparency to 0 and the color to whatever background-color you'd like for your map.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps API v3 - Gray out or remove states?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591937/google-maps-api-v3-gray-out-or-remove-states)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have thought that greying out areas using polygons etc is over complicating matters. I would simply limit the map bounds to the coordinates of the state you are interested in. An appropriate question is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099345/google-maps-api-3-limit-pan-map-bounds).